# How to add verbose name after a field in Admin - Django

Tags: python, django, verbose

I have inserted a verbose name for a field in my models (Boolean Field) and when displaying in the admin, the checkbox is shown before the verbose name.

How can I do so that the checkbox shows **after** the verbose name in the admin console?!

Or is there another way of assigning a specific label to a field other than the fieldname so that it shows correctly in the admin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to go to.

```
/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html
```

template.
Here you can see source code like.

```
         {% if field.is_checkbox %}
                        {{ field.field }} {{ field.label_tag }}
```

Just change code to :

```
      {% if field.is_checkbox %}
                         {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field.field }}
```

We put `field.label_tag` before `field.field`

Answer (score 0):

This is the way django shows Boolean fields in Admin, whether u give verbose name or not.
If you really bother about it, So you can override Django admin templates. [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template)
 for more detail...